# How to create re-usable select component in angular but without using <Select> and <option> tag?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to create re-usable select component in angular but without using  **Select** and **option** tag?

Comment: where you not want to use `select` or `option` tags? (parent component or the reusable component itself?

Comment: @AbdelrhmanElSayed, in reusable component.

Comment: Why do you don't want to use <select> and <option> in your re-usable component?

Comment: Why you don't need to use `select` tag in reusable select component?
You should implement the native select functionality with normal elements and I think it's will be complex and not best practice

Comment: I don't know that you guys noticed it. But <option> tag don't allow us to use CSS (like border, padding, etc). that is the only reason to use other tags except to the option tag.

Comment: BTW thank you @Rasidre and Abdelrhman to look into this.